# React Hammer - making Pinch (zoom) work

Tags: reactjs, hammer.js

I am making a component with React and Hammer using [react-hammer](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-hammerjs) and I can't seem to get the pinch to work! I have successfully used the swipe events, but got stuck here.

This is the piece of code:

```
          <Hammer onPinch={this.onPinchStart.bind(this)} options={{
               recognizers: {
                  pinch: {
                    enable: true
                  }
               }
            }}>
            <div className="investigate__panel--zoom">
              <p>PINCH TO ZOOM</p>
            </div>
          </Hammer>
```

and this is the event - I am just trying to get it to do ANYTHING at this point:

```
  onPinchStart() {
   console.log('zooming!');
  }
```

Can anyone explain why this event is not being called?

Comment: Have you tried `onPinchStart` instead of `onPinch`?

Comment: Thank you, it is working now!